# Create Table with Int-attribute which can only use values between 6 and 36

Tags: mysql, check-constraints, learning

Hello I'm learning for my databases examination and in one exercise they asking for creating a table with a attribute which can only use values between 6 and 36. How do I solve it?

We used in the course always Oracle databases and not mysql.

Here is the original text of the exercise (in german language):

Erstellen Sie eine Tabelle PROJEKTE. Projekte haben einen Namen, eine 
Projektnummer, die Personalnummer eines Professors, der die Rolle des Projektleiters 
übernimmt, einen Starttermin und eine Laufzeit (ganze Zahlen zwischen 6 und 36).

Comment: I use in my local pc mysql

Comment: For your problem - and if you cannot change to Postgres or other DBMS - there is a workaround in MySQL: [check constraint does not work?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work/22019#22019)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the intention is for you to create a table and a `CHECK` constraint on the table

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  col1 integer check( col1 between 6 and 36 )
);
```

And a demonstration that it works

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE foo (
  2    col1 integer check( col1 between 6 and 36 )
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 5 );
insert into foo values( 5 )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C0047240) violated


SQL> insert into foo values( 37 );
insert into foo values( 37 )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C0047240) violated


SQL> insert into foo values( 12 );

1 row created.
```

Comment: @Kingalione: MySQL does not support check constraints (but won't tell you). If you are serious about learning SQL you should pick a better (more modern, closer to the standard) DBMS (such as Postgres)