# Database : what design to point on two possibilities?

Tags: mysql

I am designing a datamodel for a new project.

One of the requirements specifies that some objects can point either a person or a company.

**What is the smartest way to achieve that?**

I have thought about a table link "actor" like this (drawn with the excellent [yUML.me](https://yuml.me/edit/d97f0b43) BTW) :

[image]

In the `actor` table, according to `actor_type`, `person_id` or `company_id` is a foreign key on its corresponding table or is `NULL`. This way, when `one_table` wants to retrieve details about the `actor`, I start by checking the `actor_type` field and retrieve either `person_id` or `company_id`.

**It is working, but I am looking for a better design.**
[Here is the link for editing the diagram](https://yuml.me/edit/d97f0b43)

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that you don't need the `actor_type` table at all, since there is just those two types. As the column and table names are already human readable, even more actor types could be added the same way.

The actor type is neither necessary for ruling out which one this actor is, since the other(s) can be left `NULL`. Only one being `NOT NULL` can also be made mandatory with constrains, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE actor
ADD CONSTRAINT OnlyOneActor
CHECK (
   (CASE WHEN company IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     + CASE WHEN person IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   = 1
)
```

However, this won't actually work as supposed in MySQL: [Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) states that

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

You can achieve the same functionality in MySQL by using a [TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) instead, e.g.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER OnlyOneActor BEFORE INSERT ON actor
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (
     (CASE WHEN company IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN person IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     != 1) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Only one type of actor allowed.';
  END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the way to create such complex rules. I will study the fact to not use actor_type table.

Comment: MySQL does not support check constraints. See: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work

Comment: MySQL _supports_ `CHECK`, but any of its database engines doesn't actually check constraints. Even InnoDB only checks foreign constrains. Answer updated accordingly.