# How to detect a circular reference in a hierarchy table?

Tags: mysql, hierarchy

I have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentId INT NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES MyTable(Id);
select * from MyTable
desc MyTable

INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, ParentId) VALUES (0, 0);
 INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, ParentId) VALUES    (1, 0);
 INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, ParentId) VALUES    (2, 4);
 INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, ParentId) VALUES    (3, 2);
 INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, ParentId) VALUES    (4, 3);
```

How to find a circular reference in table references?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a thought:

1. Add a column `depth SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'`
2. Repeatedly bump `depth` to be at least 1 more than the parent:

   `UPDATE MyTable AS child
     JOIN MyTable AS parent ON child.ParentId = parent.Id
     SET child.depth = GREATEST(child.depth, parent.depth + 1)
     WHERE child.Id != 0;   -- the root says at depth=0`
3. If rows affected drops to 0, you have no loops.
4. After awhile, any nodes in loop(s) will have large depth values.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me without the `WHERE child.id != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

[You can't do this in MySQL](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3464) without [complex triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work). In PostgreSQL, because you have `CHECK` constraints, it's very simple though

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  Id       INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ParentId INT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE ( greatest(id,parentid), least(id,parentid) )
);
```

Comment: How does `UNIQUE ( greatest(id,parentid), least(id,parentid) )` saves us from the example posted? `(2,4), (3,2), (4,3)`